# beyond frame max size

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

In the source code of `rabbit.app`, frame has max size `{frame_max,131072}`. 
If the message's size beyond the limit, will message will be refused to send or the message will be divided and then to be sent again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message will be split into several `frames` if it is larger than the `frame_max` variable, see section 2.3.5.2 in the [AMQP specification](http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf). On the receiving side it is reassembled automatically and you are presented with the message.

The actual frame size used may be different from the configured `frame_max` as it is negotiated with clients. I think the frame size is configurable mainly for performance tuning, see the comments in the [RabbitMQ configuration docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)